# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted 2 in django 1.8.5

Tags: python, django, csrf

I Know This question asked many time.

My CSRF token was working fine. but now it is giving error:

```
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted 2
```

I try many things like removing cookie, history and changing the full url in form action but nothing is work.

**HTML** form

```
 <form method="POST" action="/daily_sale/">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="panel-heading">

                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Search</button>
                            <span class="pull-right">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="form-group pull-left">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start Date" value = "{{start_date}}">
                            </span>
                            <span class="pull-right">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="form-group pull-right">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" placeholder="End  Date" value="{{end_date}}">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I also try with changing action in `form tag`

```
action="http://localhost:9002/daily_sale/"
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect


@login_required(login_url='/login_form/')
def dailySale(request):
user_id = request.user.id

reports = Reports()

if request.method == 'GET':
    # do some thing

if request.method == 'POST':
    print "inside post method"
    start_date = request.POST.get('start')
    end_date = request.POST.get('end')
    print "start  = ", start_date,"\n end  = ",end_date
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    month = request.POST.get('month')
    sale = reports.getSaleData(start_date,end_date,user_id)
    day = sale[0]
    sale_value = sale[1]
    sale_qty = sale[2]
    sale_data = zip(day, sale_value, sale_qty)

    sal = reports.get_sale_wise_channel(start_date,end_date,user_id)
    channel = sal[0]
    brand = sal[1]
    category = sal[2]
    selling_price = sal[3]
    quantity_sold = sal[4]
    percentage = sal[5]

    returns = reports.getReturns(start_date,end_date,user_id)
    order_item_ids = returns[1]
    order_date = returns[0]
    channel = returns[2]
    sku = returns[3]
    return_data = zip(order_item_ids, order_date, channel,sku)
    sal_data = zip(channel,brand,category,selling_price,quantity_sold,percentage)



    context_dict = {'sale_data':sale_data,
                     'sal_data':sal_data,                        
                     'start_date':start_date,
                     'end_date':end_date,
                    'month':month,
                    'year':year}
    return render(request, 'daily_sale.html', context_dict)
```

Its working fine with get method or first time when it run.

But when we try with POST method then it is giving error.

Comment: You need to update csrf token each time: `update(csrf(request)` .

Comment: Where I should Put this line with render of get or anywhere else

Comment: You need to update the token each time a new template rendered, so in GET part.

Comment: I have no form with get method

Comment: Sorry try to add it to your post like this context_dict.update(csrf(request))

Comment: I import  from `django.core.context_processors import csrf`   then add this `context_dict.update(csrf(request))` into get method in view.py file  but still giving error

Comment: So update your question with your new error please. csrf was missing. There may be other errors too.

Comment: there is same error but this time It will run only once  I use this line in get method     `return render(request, 'daily_sale.html', context_dict.update(csrf(request)))`   then It take Post request Only one time but when try another post metod It is giving that error again

Comment: I guess it means you need to have the same csrf update on your get method.

Comment: Ya i have Updated on get  and when I add this on both `get and post method` then It is running without error but also don't showing any data

Comment: Then you do not handle form data properly. That might be another question :). I suggest you to use ModelForms instead, which is much cleaner specially for complicated forms. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Can you check that the CSRF token is sent correctly from your browser (using dev tools)? The {% csrf_token %} template tag should take care of updating etc, and the middleware should take care of checking (as it does, as it's giving an error). You shouldn't need to do anything special for normal forms. So is the token in the HTML, and is it being sent?

Answer (score 1):

To solve `(403) CSRF verification` error,  you need to update your csrf toke in the request context each time that you render the form:

So add these to your both GET and POST methods

```
context_dict.update(csrf(request))
```

And don't forget to import csrf at top of your views:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
```

If you still have problem in processing the form, consider using [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) which is recommended and more robust way of processing forms in django.